# Magento - How to add the "images" tab (like it apears on product-edit) to category/ cms pages?

Tags: php, image, magento, edit, categories

in short:
I want to be able to assign dynamic number of images to any page on the site,
but right now i have this option only when i edit products ("images" tab).
I want the same tab when i edit categories or cms pages as well.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: use the rich-text editor in the backend, and just add an image...

Comment: Thought about it, but i need that editor for other content.
Also - i'm looking for a comfortable/organized way to do that stuff.

Comment: Add an attribute in which you store a link to an image?

Comment: Already tried, but it's not what i'm looking for.
I like the way it works in the product-edit & i think that if i'll add a similar tab to categories/ cms pages it would be easy to manage for any level of user.